# listbox item forecolor change

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, listbox, listboxitem

Does anyone know why the Listbox1.Refresh() command may not trigger the ListBox1_DrawItem sub every time?

In Microsoft Visual Basic 2010, a listbox has a forcolor and backcolor property. These properties change the forcolour and backcolor for all the items in the listbox. By default there is no property for the forecolor and backcolor of an individual item on a listbox, I am aware there is on a list view but I would still wish to use a listbox.
I am trying to have the ability to change the forecolor and backcolor properties of individual items in the listbox.
To do this the listbox's draw item sub must be used with the listbox's drawmode property set to OwnerDrawFixed. Then using a brush colour along with the e.graphics the forecolor or backcolor can be changed.
I have seen and followed examples of how to do this for the currently selected item. Such as the one from [ehow's website](http://www.ehow.co.uk/how_8494128_change-listbox-items-visual-basic.html).
What I am tiring to do however is change the colour of the litsbox item as it is added depending on a variable.

Here is my code:

```
    Private Sub listbox_add()

        Me.ListBox1.Items.Add(listbox_text(list_num)) ' adds the line to the list box
        add_item_colour = True
        ListBox1.Refresh()

End Sub



    Private Sub ListBox1_DrawItem(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventArgs) Handles ListBox1.DrawItem
    Dim myBrush As Brush = Brushes.Black

    e.DrawBackground()
    If add_item_colour = True Then
        If blue_message = True Then
            myBrush = Brushes.Blue
        Else
            myBrush = Brushes.Black
        End If
        e.Graphics.DrawString(ListBox1.Items.Item(list_num), ListBox1.Font, myBrush, _
        New RectangleF(e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y, e.Bounds.Width, e.Bounds.Height))
        add_item_colour = False
    End If
    e.DrawFocusRectangle()
End Sub
```

The listbox_text is a string array that stores the string being added, the list_num is a integer that increments when new items are added to the listbox and the blue_message is a Boolean that it true when I want a blue message and false when I don't.

The problem I seem to be having is that Listbox1.Refresh() command does not seem to be triggering the ListBox1_DrawItem sub every time it is called. I found this by using brake points. Does anyone know why this might be the case and how I could fix it?

Thanks, any help on this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

First of all I suggest you to use background worker instead of directly writing down your code on UI thread.

Please refer the code below:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Brush myBrush = Brushes.Blue;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.backgroundWorker1.DoWork += backgroundWorker1_DoWork;
        this.backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted += backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted;
        this.backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(this);
    }

    private void listBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        e.DrawBackground();
        e.Graphics.DrawString(listBox1.Items[e.Index].ToString(), listBox1.Font, myBrush, new RectangleF(e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y, e.Bounds.Width, e.Bounds.Height));
        e.DrawFocusRectangle();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(button1);
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(button2);
    }

    void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.listBox1.Refresh();
    }

    void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Argument == this)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add("p1");
            listBox1.Items.Add("p2");
        }
        else if (e.Argument == this.button1)
        {
            myBrush = Brushes.Red;
            listBox1.Refresh();
        }
        else if (e.Argument == this.button2)
        {
            myBrush = Brushes.Green;

            if (listBox1.SelectedItem == null)
                return;

            var test = listBox1.Items[listBox1.SelectedIndex];
            listBox1.SelectedItem = test;
            var g = listBox1.CreateGraphics();
            var rect = listBox1.GetItemRectangle(listBox1.SelectedIndex);
            listBox1_DrawItem(listBox1, new DrawItemEventArgs(g, this.Font, rect, listBox1.SelectedIndex, DrawItemState.Default));
            listBox1.Refresh();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer I will certainly give your code a try. What I failed to mention before however is that this listbox_add sub will only be called from a new thread, but this is using the New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf and Thread.Start() method not the background worker, I did not mention this because it did not seem to be relevant.

Comment: Also what I am trying to achieve is a situation where the colour is changed as the item is added, hence the list_num variable to keep track of the previously added. Forgive me if I am wrong but it looks like your code is dependent on the selected listbox item.

Comment: Yes you are right, the code I have provided is just a sample of how to refresh listbox when using backgroundworker. You definitely have to make changes as per your requirement.